# Python: Printing output after each command line while the program is executing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using a unit test framework (utf) to execute my scripts for testing commands,

```
#General config commands part 2.

from utfcore import *
from utf_ssr_cli import *
import time
from utf_ssr_cli import *
import re
import collections

def general_config_second(cli):
    cli.send_cmd("config")
    #print output
    cli.send_cmd("logging events process pppoe circuit keep-after up")
    #print output
    cli.send_cmd("logging events process pppoe circuit keep-after down")
    #print output
    cli.send_cmd("logging events circuit keep-after up")
    #print output
    cli.send_cmd("logging events size max-circuits 48000")
    #print output
    cli.send_cmd("global synchronization option 2")
    #print output

cli = CLI()
general_config_second(cli)
```

I would like the output of each command to be printed after each line has been executed by my script. I need a output

Comment: I do not understand what your question is.  Perhaps because I am not familiar with 'utf'.  Did you mean to delete the setence fragment at the end?

Comment: So UTF is a python testing framework. I need to print out the output of each command inside cli.send_cmd(""). So I was wondering if there any way by which I can see the output real-time. I have tried writing it on a file.